# Recoloring TabControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, colors, tabs

I have a tab control which I want to customize. To be more specific, I want to change the color of the tab page header, as well as the color of that white line around the tab page (check first picture).

I thought of using a custom renderer to do this (similar to recoloring a menu strip, for example), but I'm not sure how to do this. I've also read that setting the `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed` may do this, but using this option makes the the tab control look as if my program was made in the '90s (check second picture).

What I really want to do is to keep the tabs simple and flat *and* change their color. Check the way tabs are in Visual Studio as an example (check third picture).

[image]

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Another picture of the tab page so that it's more clear what this "white line" is.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you use `OwnerDrawFixed` it means *you* will supply the drawing code.  If you did not hook up and use the `DrawItem` event, nothing gets drawn.  This will look much the same as yours at design time, because the event is not firing.  For design time painting, you'd have to subclass the control and use `OnDrawItem`.

```
   // colors to use
   private Color[] TColors = {Color.Salmon, Color.White, Color.LightBlue};

   private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
   {
       // get ref to this page
       TabPage tp = ((TabControl)sender).TabPages[e.Index];

       using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(TColors[e.Index]))
       {
           Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
           e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds);

           rect.Offset(1, 1);
           TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, tp.Text, 
                  tp.Font, rect, tp.ForeColor);

           // draw the border
           rect = e.Bounds;
           rect.Offset(0, 1);
           rect.Inflate(0, -1);

           // ControlDark looks right for the border
           using (Pen p = new Pen(SystemColors.ControlDark))
           {
               e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, rect);
           }

           if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected) e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }
   }
```

basic result:

[image]

The tab thumb looks a bit cramped to me and not as tall as the default.  So, I added a `TFontSize` to draw the text at a different size than the Font.

Set the `TabControl.Font` to 10 (which seems to be plenty), so that Windows draws a slightly larger thumb/header.  If you still draw the text at the default 8.25, there is more room:

```
   private float TFontSize = 8.25F;       // font drawing size
   ...
   using (Font f = new Font(tp.Font.FontFamily,TFontSize))
   {
       // shift for a gutter/padding
       rect.Offset(1, 1);                  
       TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, tp.Text, 
                     f, rect,  tp.ForeColor);
   }
```

[image]

One thing you will loose this way is the VisualStyles effect, but they would seem to clash with colored tabs anyway.

Comment: Oh, sorry for not replying. Well, I did gave you an upvote for the effort, it did change the color of the header, but the color around the control ( look at the first picture on the left (that white line)) remains the same and I haven't figured out a way yet to change that.

Comment: I'm not sure what white line in which picture you are referring to.

Comment: I added a new picture. It's this white line which goes all around the tab page. It's visible whether the `DrawMode` is set to `Normal` or `OwnerDrawFixed`.